# Makefile tells up to date, but it isn't

Tags: c++, makefile

I have nothing too fancy in my makefile, here it is.

```
main.cpp :
    g++ main.cpp -o fast.exe
```

It always says main.cpp is up to date, I tried many things but nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
fast.exe: main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -o fast.exe
```

That tells that `fast.exe` depends on `main.cpp`. If there is "nothing" in the prerequisites, make is right if it says it is up to date!

And your rule says, that your target is `main.cpp` which is wrong. You don't want build main.cpp from any other source as you typically write it by hand. If main.cpp is created from a tool, you can have main.cpp as a target in a rule and the sources / inputs for main.cpp in the prerequisites. But I did not expect that your main.cpp is tool generated.